# Why is converting from an integer to digits through str() faster than a pure Python implementation?

Tags: python, string, integer

Let's say we have an integer `n = 123` and want to convert it into constituent digits `d = [1, 2, 3]`. Among two possible options,

```
def to_digits1(n):
    return [int(c) for c in str(n)]
```

and

```
def to_digits2(n):
    d = []
    while n > 10:
        n, m = divmod(n, 10)
        d.insert(0, m)
    d.insert(0, n)
    return d
```

the former appears to be significantly faster on large inputs. For instance,

```
from cProfile import run

run('to_digits1(9999 ** 2048)')
run('to_digits2(9999 ** 2048)')
```

would yield something like:

```
         5 function calls in 0.002 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.002    0.002 to_digits.py:16(to_digits1)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 to_digits.py:17(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

and

```
         16387 function calls in 0.049 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.049    0.049 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.049    0.049 to_digits.py:20(to_digits2)
     8191    0.038    0.000    0.038    0.000 {built-in method builtins.divmod}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.049    0.049 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     8192    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
```

respectively. Why would that be, considering that the first function converts `n` to a string and then converts each character back into integers, while the second funciton seems more concise and direct?

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments, a list insert in the second example is expensive at `O(n)`. This can be fixed by using a `deque` instead of a list, like so:

```
from collections import deque

def to_digits3(n):
    d = deque()
    while n > 10:
        n, m = divmod(n, 10)
        d.insert(0, m)
    d.insert(0, n)
    return list(d)
```

and while that minimizes the cost of the insert stage, it doesn't seem to give a substantial speed-up:

```
run('to_digits3(9999 ** 2048)')

         16387 function calls in 0.038 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.038    0.038 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.038    0.038 to_digits.py:30(to_digits3)
     8191    0.035    0.000    0.035    0.000 {built-in method builtins.divmod}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.038    0.038 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     8192    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'collections.deque' objects}
```

Comment: For *starters* `d.insert(0, m)` is *very inefficient* making your function quadratic time on the number of digits. But in general, Python is slow, but built-in functions will be much faster than any equivalent operation you do by hand.

Comment: You should fix the `d.insert(0, n)` for a better comparison – it adds up to quadratic time in the number of output digits. `append` and reverse instead. (Edit: I guess so does the division, though.)

Comment: Using a `deque` will speed the latter function up somewhat, but doesn't provide an order-of-magnitude optimization.

Comment: The simple answer is that `str()` is written in optimized C code, not interpreted Python code. The interpreter adds lots of overhead.

Comment: `str` can also divide the number in place, creating a total of one intermediate object at all. Each `int` has to be exposed to Python – two every loop.

Comment: In the second and third example, `divmod()` seems to take up the vast majority of execution time. Wouldn't that also be a standard function written in C?

Comment: It's not as bad as measured anyway.  Profiling adds overhead.  Use the `timeit` module and I get 1.93us and 2.48us.  The second is only 1.285x slower instead of 24.5x slower.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: That's way faster than what I see - are you sure you used the right inputs? One call should take milliseconds.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, typo...I had `*` instead of `**`.  I got 3.05ms and 64ms (and 51.8ms for deque).  21x difference...`timeit` is still the better measure, though.

Comment: This algorithm is fundamentally slow. It's not just the `d.insert(0, m)` calls - the algorithm itself is worse than quadratic time. Even the C-level built-in implementation has a similar problem. It's possible to do better with a [divide-and-conquer radix conversion algorithm and a better underlying division algorithm](https://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix), but CPython doesn't do that, because the code required is way more complex.

Comment: You can read the [current implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/044a1048ca93d466965afc027b91a5a9eb9ce23c/Objects/longobject.c#L1592), which has other optimizations like getting an upper bound on the number of digits and doing long division on a higher power of 10 base, though actually fewer optimizations than I expected. (There are fast fixed-size int-to-decimal-string functions out there that it doesn’t use.) Also, keep in mind that CPython’s inner division of a fixed-sized integer by a constant gets optimized to not involve division instructions by the C compiler.

Comment: `def: to_digits(): return list(str(n))` is also about twice as fast (1.41ms) than `to_digits1`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Well that doesn't do the integers conversion does it.

Comment: Faster than `to_digits1` and silly, by the way: `list((b"%i" % (n,)).translate(bytes.maketrans(b"0123456789", b"\0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\10\11")))`

Comment: @wim Well sh*t not paying attention today.  Should be writing unit tests I guess :P

Comment: 5 function calls vs 16387 function calls btw